# Issue with jquery prop ('selected')

Tags: jquery

Why is this function not making the applicable selection on the dropdown #attribute136!? The console.log at the beginning of the function is logging the correct value, but unless the value is '3' (specifically) the value doesn't log and the correct item is not added to cart. Item's with value number '3' DO add to cart!

```
function selectAndAddToCart(value)
{
    console.log('The selectAndAddToCart onclick value is ' + value);
    $j('#attribute136 option[value=' + value + ']').prop('selected', true);//make the applicable selection

        console.log($j('#attribute136').val()); //this keeps logging '3'

        //initiate add to cart function
        productAddToCartForm.submit(this); 
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: What does `console.log($j('#attribute136 option[value=' + value + ']').length)` give you?

Comment: Why not `$j('#attribute136').val(value)`?

Comment: why don't you use :$j('#attribute136').val(value); instead of:$j('#attribute136 option[value=' + value + ']').prop('selected', true); It should have the same effect and is much simpler.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar's answer below, but as to why your original code isn't working...it could fail if there are spaces or other non-alphanumeric characters in the value; the workaround for that is to enclose the value with quotes, e.g. `[value="' + value + '"]`. In some cases you may need to escape `value` as well. But again, just using the `val()` method as suggested is much easier in this case.

Comment: $j('#attribute136').val(value) did not work! And console.log($j('#attribute136 option[value=' + value + ']').length) yields 0...

Comment: Then what does `console.log($j('#attribute136 option').length)` give you? and `console.log($j('#attribute136 option').get())`? It appears as though either the option you are looking for doesn't exist, or it doesn't have the value you think it has.

Comment: Length of select is 3 test-40.html:636
Get is [object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement]

Comment: Ah, that must be an IEConsole. i was hoping to be able to see the values.

Comment: LOL no chrome. I'll give you firebug in a second. There is also validation on it that is coming up as no option selected. I tried to remove it with $j('#attribute136').removeClass('validation-failed').addClass('validation-passed'); I still am able to add any that have a value of '3' specifically but none of the others.

Comment: It logs the same thing in firebug.. Okay, so I inspected elements and they do not have the correct values. Therefore I am going to have to obtain the text within the node and make the selection based on that value.

Comment: Wow... so the value does not correspond to the text. My bad. So instead I am trying to select the option with matching text with the following code but it returns cannot call method find of null: var optionToSelect = $('#attribute136').find('option[text="' + value + '"]').val();

Comment: I posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408279/make-option-selection-based-off-text-in-option-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function selectAndAddToCart(value)
{
    console.log('The selectAndAddToCart onclick value is ' + value);
    var vals = $j('#attribute136').val() || [];
    vals.push(value);
    $j('#attribute136').val(vals);

    console.log($j('#attribute136').val());

    //initiate add to cart function
    productAddToCartForm.submit(this); 
}
```

For a multi-valued `<select>`, `val()` returns and takes an array.

Comment: Only weird thing is there is really no point of `$j('#attribute136').val(vals);` if `var vals = $j('#attribute136').val()`

Comment: @wirey I'm adding to `vals` on the line before that.

Comment: Object has no method 'push' ??

Comment: Updated answer to handle the initial case where no options are selected. IMHO, jQuery should return an empty array rather than `null` in this case.

Comment: I'm getting 502 bad gateway on a weird URL when this function is called with this code

Comment: That sounds like a problem elsewhere in your code, like the submit handler for `productAddToCartForm`. I don't see how my changes could have caused that error.

Comment: You were right. I was selecting based off value and didn't realize the options were populated with a completely different value. So now I am trying to select based off the text in the node. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408279/make-option-selection-based-off-text-in-option-element