# Make option selection based off text in option element

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to select the option in a dropdown list that has the text value passed into the function, get it's value, and then select the option with that value. Can you see why the this isn't working?

```
  function selectAndAddToCart(value)
    {
        console.log('The selectAndAddToCart onclick value is ' + value);
        var optionToSelect = $j('#attribute136').find('option[text="' + value + '"]').val(); //select the option with the node text that equals value
//select the option with the node text that equals value
        var vals = $j('#attribute136').val() || [];
        vals.push(optionToSelect);
        $j('#attribute136').val(vals);

        //initiate add to cart function
        productAddToCartForm.submit(this); 
    }
```

Comment: Have you linked to jQuery properly, and does the `#attribute136` element exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using noConflict, renaming `$` to `$j`, yet on the failing selector you are using `$`, and not `$j`!

I'd do :

```
var optionToSelect = $j('option', '#attribute136').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(value) != -1;
}).val();
```

But that's only because I don't much care for the `contains()` selector:

```
$("#attribute136 option:contains(" + value + ")");
```

Comment: Nice catch...completely overlooked that. +1

Comment: The contains selector didn't work for me but your filter did! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put the value in quotes. Try

```
var optionToSelect = $('#attribute136').find('option[text="' + value + '"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#attribute136 option:content("+value")");
```

is the selector you want.

Comment: $j("#attribute136 option:content("+value+")").val(); yields 'unrecognized expression: content'